# How to change Stars in Webform-star module?

Tags: 7, webforms, rating

I have just implemented the Fivestar option in one of the evaluation form created by webform, I used the Fivestar module and Webform-fivestar module. But now I want to change the stars with different layout or design. In some of the article i read that we can change in manage display tab of the contentype but that option is not applicable for webform components. So that changing option is not available in the webform configurations. So please help me how to achieve this.

Comment: Currently it is not configurable with webform fivestar. See https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_fivestar/issues/2377729 It shouldn't be that hard to add though, I'll have a quick look into it.

Comment: Also this issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_fivestar/issues/2071161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webform-fivestar module currently doesn't have the option to select which star widget to use, however there is a patch you can apply at https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_fivestar/issues/2071161

There is information regarding how to apply patches at https://www.drupal.org/patch/apply

You can then select the widget per component, when editing the component, in the display settings (see screenshot).

[image]

Comment: Thanks rooby. I applied this patch but where will i get the option of selecting different widgets?

Comment: @Suraj I have added more information to the answer.

Comment: Now it works fine, thanks for that. Is there any way to increase the size of the stars?

Comment: You could override the CSS to change the size, however you would have to also override the images that the CSS refers to and create larger images to go with it. OR you could create your own widget style. There are some instructions for that at https://www.drupal.org/node/234391

Comment: Although that doco hasn't been updated for a while so it might not be up to date.